# Run Pipeline Batch button disabled

Tags: pipelines, data-exchange-framework

I installed Data Exchange Framework, Sitecore Provider for Data Exchange Framework, and Dynamics CRM Provider for Data Exchange Framework (all 1.2.0 rev 161212) in my Sitecore instance. I have tested the connection and confirmed that a connection with Dynamics CRM is established.
[image]

And when I'll try to run a pipeline batch, the Run Pipeline Batch is grayed out (disabled) and can't be clicked for every pipeline batch.
[image]

This is strange because I had this working once in a different instance with same versions installed (I was able to sync Accounts aside from the default Contacts etc). But when I created another and another one, both buttons are disabled. I've followed the walkthrough but this is really bothering me for almost two days now. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you create a new tenant it is disabled by default.

You need to enable it. On the tenant item on **Administration** section you have a checkboxfield **Enabled**

Please see below image:

[image]

You can enabled or disabled a single pipeline batch.

On the pipeline batch processor item on **Administration** section you have a checkboxfield **Enabled** Please verify if is enabled, maybe someone else disabled it.

[image]

Comment: Oh my! The tenant item itself is not enabled but the pipeline batches are. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

The one of the way do not forget enable tenants or pipeline batches before running you can use a custom extension - "[Gutters for Sitecore Data Exchange Framework](https://github.com/vladcheg/Sitecore.DataExchange.Gutters)".

[image]

[image]

Comment: This one's very handy and helpful, thanks for sharing this!